# Is there a term for the function $\operatorname{sign}(x) \times |x|^a$?

Tags: functions, exponential-function, exponentiation

I wanted to use a power function for  some procedural generation, but also needed to preserve the sign of the input and not be limited to uneven integer exponents. This seems like a basic enough use that I am surprised that I could not find a specific term for the function.
Also, is there any simple alternative with similar properties?

Comment: You mean, a power series?.. well it's already a polynomial.. it's just a piecewise function

Comment: I suspect that there is no assigned term because I suspect that there is no assigned term to sign(x).  The reason that I suspect this is because I have seen formulas that expressed sign(x) by $\frac{x}{|x|}.$

Comment: Right, should I change the title to $|x|^{a+1}/x$? The question still stands. In the series $x^3$, $x^5$, $x^7$ ..., I want a function that naturally fits between (and is not an even integer, changing the sign of the negative part).

Comment: I have seen *signed power function* term used here and there, at least it has the merit of simplicity.